# Hangouts Chat - Send link to add bot to space

Tags: google-hangouts

I am building a Google Hangouts Chat chatbot.

I need my bot to prompt users, following a dialog with another user. However, a conversation may not have been started with these users yet and I do not have permission to start one without being added to a DM space.

The current solution I envision is to prompt users by email. However, I cannot find a direct link to the bot, or that adds the bot to the user's space. Does such a link exist? Or do I have to send an email with instructions such as "Please go to chat.google.com and add the bot to a conversation"? I'm afraid this will generate strong churn.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bots can only be added to a space by a user so yes, you will need to instruct the user to add them manually

Comment: Hi cyntht, yes I am aware of this but it would be much better to have a link to provide users, even if users must confirm before opening the conversation. I'm assuming this does not exist yet (but it should). Thanks!

Comment: This is another example of how Google does not "get" chat and bots.  As of Jan 2021 there continues to be no way to do this